# Inbox needs to be fixed: Unread messages should be marked clearly until read

Tags: feature-request

Let's say I have 10 new messages. The inbox icon lights up with "10". Now, when I click into the inbox to read the first message, this lighting disappears. I have to manually keep track of how many I've read, because it doesn't show me unread messages separately. Can this please be fixed? It should show all unread messages marked clearly.

Comment: This has actually been brought up several times on [metaSO] and declined repeatedly (though I can't seem to find the requests right now), so unfortunately I don't think it's going to happen.

Comment: Really??? It's been declined? Keeping new messages marked as new until read is something *every* inbox on the internet supports. Why is SE so behind?

Comment: Totally agree with this. It's exacerbated by the fact that the next time you click on your inbox it's gone away and turned into "hot questions" instead - it took me months to notice that a tiny "inbox" tab also appears.

Comment: I haven't really had this problem myself, but it probably is for the rest of the universe . . .

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this as well, it seems like a rather useful feature to have. And I've fallen afoul of this a few times before -- I don't notice some inbox messages.

My workaround is to just open all the inbox messages in new tabs, give them a precursory glance and deal with them one by one, closing tabs.

Or, you can just use [this Chrome Extension](https://stackapps.com/questions/3778/stackinbox-a-chrome-firefox-extension-that-preserves-new-stack-exchange-inbox) that does the checking for you:)